# Does spring batch support Java 8?

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to know which version of spring batch is compatible with Java 8.
Is the latest version of spring batch 2 compatible with Java 8?
Does spring batch 3 support Java 8?

Best Regards,
Yas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Batchs own documentation provides an answer to this. Deducing from the written documentation, I would assume Spring Batch 2 does **not** support Java 8.

Taken from the documentation itself

> The Spring Batch 3.0 release has five major themes:
>
> - JSR-352 Support
> - Upgrade to Support Spring 4 and **Java 8**
> - Promote Spring Batch Integration to Spring Batch
> - JobScope Support
> - SQLite Support

Further in the documentation, under section 2.3, the following is stated:

> Spring Batch now supports being run on Java 8. It will still execute on Java 6 or higher as well.

Source: [Spring Batch Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#whatsNewUpgradeToSupportSpring4andJava8)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understood it.